# react-native ERROR Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081 errorno 11

Tags: react-native

[image]

**react-native start --port=8088 not wokring**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer of this question. Actually my port 8081 is already running so need to use these command

```
lsof -i :8081
```

now you will get a list of **Process id** **(PID)** and you need to kill them with below command

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: i have also same issue but this solution is not working for me.please help me.